# Powershell Script Prompt 2 input in one go

Tags: powershell

i wanted to make one prompt to ask for 2 input in one go for e.g "D:\Test\File 1", "D:\Test\File 2
instead of this input first file path: "D:\Test\File 1",  input second file path: "D:\Test\File 2".

```
function compareTwoFiles($firstFilePath, $secondFilePath) 
{
$firstFilePath = Read-Host "Input first file path" 
$secondFilePath = Read-Host "Input second file path"

if ($firstFilePath.Length -gt $secondFilePath.Length)
    {"File 1"}
elseif ($firstFilePath.Length -lt $secondFilePath.Length)
    {"File 2"}
else {"both file has same size"}
return
}
```

Comment: `compareTwoFiles "D:\Test\File 1", "D:\Test\File 2"` you're looking to do this? Also, `.Length` in your code is giving you the length of the string being inputted to the function.

Comment: This is comparing two **strings**, nothing to do with file sizes. Was that what you actually intended to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this, input the file path and separate them with ";" or "-" or any other char, then split the input like this:

```
$input = Read-Host "Input first file path, place ';' and then other file path " 
$userInputs = $input.Split(";")

$userInputs[0]
$userInputs[1]
```

The output:

```
PS C:\Users\Awat\Desktop\testPS> .\myscript.ps1
Input first file path, place ';' and then other file path : file1.txt;file2.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
PS C:\Users\Awat\Desktop\testPS>
```

your code should be similar to this:

```
$input = Read-Host "Input first file path, place ';' and then other file path " 
$userInputs = $input.Split(";")

// Just for output....
$userInputs[0]
$userInputs[1]

if ($userInputs[0].Length -gt $userInputs[1].Length)
    {"File 1"}
elseif ($userInputs[0].Length -lt $userInputs[1].Length)
    {"File 2"}
else {"both file has same size"}
return
```

Comment: That is great news, You are welcome @bobmar :)

Comment: This is the route I would've taken as well. May I suggest adding a `.Trim()` to your `$input.Split(";")`? Would be beneficial seeing as a user may enter an extra space by accident.

Comment: Choose a different name for the `$input` variable, because that is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell. Also do as @AbrahamZinala suggested and remove leading and/or trailing whitespace.